# .nomedia + SD Card - just can't create the file, no matter what

Tags: external-sd, file-system, android-11, media-scanner

I have an ASUS Zenfone 7 Pro phone running Android 11. This phone comes with an SD card slot and so I wanted to make use of it. It stored the files great, I can read the files all good. But I cannot make my Gallery/Android System ignore any folder on the MicroSD card.

For example, I have a folder with album previews. These all show up as folders in Gallery - needlessly.

So why I can't make the file? I don't know.
If I open Solid Explorer and try to create a new empty file as `.nomedia` anywhere on the SD card, it will just time out and will fail at the task. I can only force close the app when this happens. Other apps just gave me an error, but nothing specific.

How do I overcome this limitation? Maybe it's because the SD card is formatted FAT32? But I remember using MicroSD in my old Note 4 and other phones, and they handled .nomedia just fine. What changed? Something Android 11 related?

Comment: your problem is with Solid Explorer

Comment: Try this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foobar.azmediascanner&hl=en&gl=US) to create

Comment: @beeshyams Unfortunately I was not able to open the SD Card with this app. It only shows internal storage - where Solid Explorer also worked just fine. :/ Thank you though.